# Does the New Testament ever condone violence?

Tags: new-testament

There are several passages in the New Testament like [Matthew 5:38-39](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+5:38-39):

> You have heard that it was said, "Eye for eye, and tooth for tooth." But I tell you, do not resist an evil person. If anyone slaps you on the right cheek, turn to them the other cheek also.

And also [Romans 13:1-2](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%2013:1-7):

> Let everyone be subject to the governing authorities, for there is no authority except that which God has established. The authorities that exist have been established by God. Consequently, whoever rebels against the authority is rebelling against what God has instituted, and those who do so will bring judgment on themselves.

Do these -or any other passages in the New Testament - condone violence of any sort? (In self defense, a government/social revolution, defending an attacking army, et cetera).  If there are none, then are these verses suggesting the New Testament is opposed to a person (or country) acting in self defense?

I am aware of times in the Old Testament where God instructs Israel to go to war, and I know people who will say that violence as self-defense is acceptable, but I'm curious if anything like this is ever stated or implied in the New Testament?

Comment: I tried rephrasing a bit to be more direct to the two passages I quoted, but I don't want to restrict answers from including other passages.  I'm definitely asking what the actual text says, not what people's opinions are of it, so I think this site will be a better place than Christianity

Comment: Since questions searching for a text are off-topic, I will leave this as a comment: First, Matt 5:38-39 is [famously hyperbolic](http://goo.gl/TmhGy6) and to be taken with a grain of salt. Just as we do not [pluck out our eyes or cut off our hands](http://goo.gl/Ov9UpU), the same restraint of application should apply for the rest of the hyperbolic statements. Famously, Jesus was involved in a violent episode in which he "made a whip of cords and drove [the money changers out of the temple courts... He scattered the coins ...and overturned their tables."](https://goo.gl/gL62eg).